# How do I get Jekyll scope/value pairs from config.yml

Tags: jekyll

How can I pull a default scope/value from my Jekyll _config.yml file into my default layout?

Here is part of the _config.yml

```
# default settings
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: "" # an empty string here means all files in the project
      type: posts
    values:
      author: ME
      layout: post
      class: article
```

I want to print something simple like {{ site.defaults.scope.type }}

Comment: You can grab `site.defaults` array but it will be tricky to know what are the criteria used to set default values for certain posts or pages. You'd better rely on `values` set specifically for a pattern, and get them with a `page.myValue`.

Comment: Thanks David. I was using site.defaults but it grabs the whole array, I am unable to get the values individually. I was trying to avoid the page.value because there are a ton of pages I'd have to go through. 

Would you happen to know how to pull the class value in the example above?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the value `class` by using `page.class` in a page that conforms to the path and type specified. For example:

*config.yml*

```
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: ""
      type: posts
    values:
      class: a post
  -
    scope:
      path: ""
      type: not_posts
    values:
      class: not a post
```

*_posts/****-**-**-post.html*

```
---
layout: post
---
{{ page.class }}
```

*Output*

```
a post
```